# Unable to get firebase user as soon as it is created

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-authentication

I'm creating a `Firebase` user using `firebase cloud functions` through the method:

```
(createUserClass.generateUser(data, "createUser"))
                        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<String>() {
                            @Override
                            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<String> task) {
                                acknowledgeUser();
                            }

                        })
                        .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                                acknowledgeUser();
                            }
                        });

private void acknowledgeUser(){
        FirebaseAuth auth=FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        FirebaseUser user=auth.getCurrentUser();
        user.getEmail();
    }
```

Method is such that after creating the user only, I'm calling the `acknowledgeuser()` method. I'm surprised to see the value of `FirebaseUser` instance as `null` but user is created in the `firebase console`.

Is this a bug or am I doing something wrong?Please help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`firebase.auth.getCurrentUser()` gets the current user signed in on the auth instance. Your code shows no user is signed in, after it is being created.

Comment: so if I starts new activity using intent in acknowledgeUser() method, I'll again get the null values???

Comment: Yeah, u were ryt....I see that I've to sign in separately even after creating a new account of the user.